# gstreamer client multicast UDP does not connect when multiple interfaces are up

Tags: routes, udp, gstreamer, h.264, multicast

I am using gstreamer to connect to a streaming video that is raw H.264 elementary stream over raw UDP multicast.  I find that when I have *only* `eth0` up, it connects just fine:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://239.255.43.43:4444 ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

However, when I bring up both `wlan0` and `eth0` I have problems.  I use `wlan0` as my main internet connection and `eth0` is on my local lan where the streaming video server is.  I have `wlan0` as the default route:

```
host$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

When I try to connect in this configuration, gstreamer just sits there on the `select()` call waiting for a connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to tell gstreamer which interface to use for receiving the multicast UDP stream:

```
gst-launch udpsrc multicast-iface="eth0" uri=udp://239.255.43.43:4444 ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```